# Achievements on Xbox 360 and Games for Windows Live

Tags: xbox-360, games-for-windows-live

Say I play a game on the Xbox 360 and earn some achievements. If I later buy the same game through Games for Windows Live (under the same gamertag), will those achievements show up in both places, or are they platform-specific?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As long as you sign in with the same Live account, your achievements will be *visible* on both sides of the fence.  That is, when playing a Games for Windows Live game, you will be able to view all achievements in all games for both platforms.

**However**: The Xbox 360 and GfW-Live versions count as separate games, even though they will have the same title.  So, if you play Fallout 3 on both the PC and the 360, they will not share achievements.  Yes, this also means that you can earn a total of 2000 gamerscore by earning all of the achievements on both platforms.